# Fedora 16: Failed to install scion-browser with cabal

Tags: linux, fedora, haskell, shared-libraries, cabal

It seems like on Fedora 16 `cabal` isn't able to install `scion-browser` from `hackage` because of some incompatibilities with respect to Fedora's shared objects.

When I run `cabal install scion-browser` I get:

```
...
Loading package terminfo-0.3.2.3 ... <command line>: can't load .so/.DLL for:
   ncursesw (/usr/lib64/libncursesw.so: file too short)
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
scion-browser-0.2.8 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

I already have all packages installed for `ncurses` and the required file exists, but it's not a binary or symbolic link and thus the installation fails:

```
bash-4.2$ cat /usr/lib64/libncursesw.so 
INPUT(libncursesw.so.5 -ltinfo)
```

I don't think replacing that file with a symbolic  link to `libncursesw.so.5` would be a great idea, but I can't think of any other way in order to get it installed. What should I do, please?

Comment: anyone, please?

Answer (score 1):

As described [here](http://eclipsefp.github.com/faq.html), GCC and GHC don't necessarily follow links in the same way. The fixed described worked for me.

> ```
> cd /usr/lib
> sudo mv libncurses.so libncurses.so.bak
> sudo mv libncursesw.so libncursesw.so.bak
> sudo ln -s /lib/libncurses.so.5 libncurses.so
> sudo ln -s /lib/libncursesw.so.5 libncursesw.so
> ```

Since I was on a 64 bit Fedora box, I was moving things around in /lib64 and /usr/lib64

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I already knew of this method (as I, perhaps too quickly, mentioned in my question). Symbolic links like those are likely to change with system updates soon or late, so that this would be only a temporary patch. I was searching for something to solve the problem once and for all.

Comment: Oh, so you did. Good point. Though I thought that symbolic links were the standard way to alias library names.